# In "renders loose talk about a European army ridiculous", what is "ridiculous" modifying?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis

In this sentence, what does *ridiculous* modify?

> Slow progress towards common defence procurement, let alone a shared
> doctrine, renders loose talk about a European army ridiculous.

[Source](https://www.economist.com/europe/2019/04/17/the-problem-with-eu-foreign-policy)

Comment: Compare 'painted the fence green' (or 'painted the 6ft-high fence at the rear of the garden green'). Although 'ridiculous' is arguably a depictive rather than a resultative here. So perhaps 'left the 6ft-high fence at the rear of the garden brown'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the context is behind a paywall.

Comment: "Ridiculous" is not a modifier, but a complement. "Loose talk about a European army" is the object of "renders" and the adjective "ridiculous" is then objective predicative complement.

Comment: @Greybeard I'm asking a question that should be answered just from the given quote. Why do you need to access the source anyway?

Comment: @Greybeard That’s not a valid reason to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> "Ridiculous" is not a modifier, but a complement. "Loose talk about a European army" is the object of "renders" and the adjective "ridiculous" is then objective predicative complement.